# How to handle dictionaries between different Python scripts

Tags: python, json, dictionary, pickle

I have 2 Python scripts, which collect data from diffent APIs (also websockets) and store them in a dictionary. So I have 2 dictionaries, which are updated several times per second, up to 1000 times per second.
What I do now, I export these files as a `.json`file and then import them in a 3rd script to compare both dictionaries.
The export takes some time, since both dictionaries are about 5 MB file size. The import in the 3rd script also takes time and can fail, because while script 1 and 2 write the `.json` file, it is not possible to import them.
Now I'm looking for a solution to get these files in the compare-script 3 in real time, if possible.
For now I tried to export the dicts as a `.json`file and aswell I tried with pickle module, but both ways have the same disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

You're somewhat complicating things by having three separate processes that pass data between them. Writing json to the file system is slow and unreliable as you've discovered. There's several different approaches you could take to solve this problem.

- You could use something like [protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) to transfer data between your scripts, which is a faster version of json basically.
- Or you could use a shared database (sqlite is simple and should do what you need) that all three scripts connect to transfer data.
- Or instead of having the three scripts as separate processes, you could move them all into the same process and use threading and a shared queue solution.
- Reconsider the whole approach and decide if it needs to be three separate threads of execution, i.e. instead of gathering data in real time, can you gather data for the last 10 minutes from both sources and process that, then repeat again in 10 minutes.

There are many different ways you can solve your problem, and the best way is really down to what you're most comfortable with or interested in learning.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply! I already tested to put everything in 1 script, but this is too much load for 1 process, that's why it is much slower than 3 different scripts.
I think the most interesting idea is the sqlite database, but is it possible to connect to 1 database with 3 different scripts at the same time, without getting read/write problems?

Comment: Yes SQLite is [ACID](https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html#:~:text=SQLite%20implements%20serializable%20transactions%20that,power%20failure%20to%20the%20computer.), which is fancy comp sci for writes and reads are transactional, and can handle multiple concurrent connections without stepping on each others toes. Learning how to use an sql database is a good skill to develop, there are other types of data storage like [redis](https://redis.io/) available nowadays but no harm is learning the old stuff, you'll encounter it on many projects in the future.